# How to use \newline in a macro?

Tags: macros, line-breaking

I want to introduce `\newline` after the figure label instead of `:`. I am aware that `caption` package does this via `\captionsetup`. However, I would like to do it without it.

I read from the `memoir` class manual (page no - 214) about the trick of declaring an extra argument for `\fnum@figure` and not using it, which gobbles the undesired colon from `\@makecaption`. Now, for `memoir` class I can introduce `\newline` instead of `:` as the label separator. It works.

**Original caption:**

[image: Original caption]

**Modified in Memoir class:**

[image: Modified in memoir]

This trick also works for `scrreprt`. However, for `scrreprt`, `:` disappears but `\newline` is not introduced. I have also tried `\\`, `\\*` and `\vspace{\baselineskip}`. None of them work.

**Modified caption without ":" but no \newline**

[image: modified for scrreprt]

Introducing `\newline` at the start of the `\caption` also doesn't work.

I think that I am making some rookie mistake here. I have read that most macros do not distinguish between spaces and `\newlines`. Is this the reason why this won't work?

Please let me know a workaround.

```
%\documentclass{memoir}
\documentclass{scrreprt}

%Memoir manual page no - 214
%Note the extra unused argument.
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}[1]{\textsc{\figurename~\thefigure} \newline \sffamily}
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{3cm}{2cm}
    \caption{A Caption}
    %\caption{\newline A Caption}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many caption styles put the caption into `\mbox` so the width can be measured and like all LR boxes or table `l` entries they are then one-line. In any case you should not be putting explict line breaks into the caption argument but rather controlling the caption style if that is what you want. As you say caption package does this for the standard classes, but memoir and scrrprt probably have their own caption style setup commands which should be used (not really familiar with either)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle caption package works with Memoir and scrreprt as well. I am just trying to do this on my own to learn.

Comment: well it is easy to define a simple `\@makecaption` with a two line layout but harder to fit in with all the other features those classes may add like automatic caption positioning, continuation captions etc, so it depends a bit _what_ you want to learn. will post an example...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I copied the macro definitions of `\@makecaption` from report/scrreprt classes, then redefined it with `\newline` instead of `:`. It doesn't work. But if `:` is replaced by `--`, it does.

Comment: yes that's expected try `\mbox{a\newline b}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

As an example this is a simple caption handler that makes a two line layout (if your captions may be long you could change `ll` to `lp{5cm}` or whatever you need for multi-line version) it does not respect all the options the class may have controlling caption positioning.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

%Memoir manual page no - 214
%Note the extra unused argument.
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}[1]{\textsc{\figurename~\thefigure}}
\def\@@makecaption#1#2#3{%
{\centering\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\csname fnum@\@captype\endcsname&{}\tabularnewline
&#3\end{tabular}\par}
}
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{3cm}{2cm}
    \caption{A Caption}
    %\caption{\newline A Caption}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess the key idea is to use `tabular` environment instead of adding a `\newline`.

Comment: You need to typeset the caption in a construct that _allows_ multiple lines so a tabular or (more usually) a parbox or somesuch, if you'd used a parbox here though you would have to work a bit harder to get the indentation style but using a tabular it is easy as the alignment is automatic

Comment: From `report.cls`, `\@makecaption` definition has a line `\sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}`. Could I add `\tabular` environment in the box to achieve the same result as your example?

Comment: report.cls first does that and if the box is small uses it otherwise resets as a multi-line parbox, but in your example the text is small and fits on a line so it will be used, but yes you could use the same definition as above (but with one `@` and just two arguments not three in report)